# css override issue using squarespace

Tags: squarespace

I have tried a few times but cannot seen to access an html element via the ID tag.  for example I have tried the following in the css override window.

```
#collection-yui_3_17_2_1_1407045131078_1860 #body{background-color: #262626;}
#collection-yui_3_17_2_1_1407045131078_1860 .body{background-color: #262626;}
#collection-yui_3_17_2_1_1407045131078_1860 {background-color: #262626;}
#collection-yui_3_17_2_1_1407045131078_1860 #body{background-color: blue;}
```

Non of these seem to work.  Can anyone point me to where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some of the HTML? We don't know if you are targeting properly the elements without the html. (mainly the body tag element and the element you wan to target)

Comment: Sure.  Here is an example:  <div id="yui_3_17_2......38577_3848" class="sqs-block-content"><p id="yui_3_17_2....76138577_3847"> boy</p></div>

Answer (score 1):

Use !important to the attributes.. It will help

Answer (score 1):

You can't access it because SquareSpace ID tags are dynamic.  So even if you are able to access the ID it is session based and your code will not work once the screen is refreshed.  You have to access the object category in you CSS in SquareSpace.

Formatting for the string depends on which template you are using.